# Build a dataframe based on the values returned by different function calls from a forloop

Tags: python, dataframe

I have 5 different functions which give me different outputs. These functions are running on images kept in a folder on my local system. I want to write the output of these images neatly into a dataframe. How can I do that or is there any better way to put it into a tabular format? I will need to export this later.

```
def main():
photo='Test.jpg'
for photos in os.listdir():
    label=detect_labels(photos)
    faces = detect_faces(photos)
    text = detect_text(photos)
    celebrity=recognize_celebrities(photos)
    moderation = moderate_image(photos)
```

The output should be something like this where the column names are [File Name,Labels,Faces,Text,Celebrity,Moderation] as headers. And then in the subsequent rows I will have the respective values returned by the functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a list of lists for all the photos in you folder and then after the loop is completed add that list of lists to a dataframe by creating a new one. This will append values row-wise.

```
def main():
photo='Test.jpg'
for photos in os.listdir():
    label=detect_labels(photos)
    faces = detect_faces(photos)
    text = detect_text(photos)
    celebrity=recognize_celebrities(photos)
    moderation = moderate_image(photos)
    full_list.append([photos,label,faces,text,celebrity,moderation])
df = pd.DataFrame(full_list, columns = ['FileName','Labels','Faces','Text','Celebrity','Moderation'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a empty list.
for each Photo create a temporary dataframe in your specified format.
use pd.concat() to combine all temporary dataframes in that list into one single dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

def main():
    photo='Test.jpg'
    lst_collect = []
    for photos in os.listdir():
        df_photo = pd.DataFrame()
        df_photo["label"] = detect_labels(photos)
        df_photo["faces"] = detect_faces(photos)
        lst_collect.append(df_photo)
    df_return = pd.concat(lst_collect)
    return df_return
```